# Correct translation of sentence with できていません

Tags: translation, verbs, syntax

I am confused with the use of できていません in sentence :

> 明日の宿題のレポートがまだ１枚もできていません

When I checked the dictionary it shows that できる means CAN(DO)/ BE ABLE TO while ている is for present progressive so I translate it as:

> I cannot do/am not doing tomorrow's homework/report yet.

However when I checked google translate it gives me:

> I have not yet made one report for tomorrow's homework.

Questions:
1. Where did Google get *made*?
2. What is the correct translation?
3. Can we replace できる with おわる?

Thank you,

Sheena

Comment: Hint:  できる has several meanings. Try checking a better dictionary. Also you cannot use おわる because the subject of the sentence is 宿題のレポート and that's not the thing/person doing the finishing.

Comment: Also ている isn't always present progressive. See this link https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/when-is-v%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-the-continuation-of-action-and-when-is-it-the-continuation-of-state

Comment: Also, there's another small problem with your google translated sentence: the construction: [一 + counter + も + negative] means roughly "not even one" => no one, none, nothing etc. So it would roughly mean: "I still haven't written [the other main meaning of 出来る is "to be ready, to be completed" => できていません = polite: is not completed/ready] even one page of the report for tomorrow's homework."